# jquery command to count the number of jpg files

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

wat is the jquery command to count the number of jpg image files in my document..

the command to count the image files:

```
$('#div').html($('img').length );
```

bt then this counts all the image files with the tag- img

wat is the command to count only the .jpg files..

I tried this

```
$('#div').html($("[img$='.jpg']").length);
```

but this does not gives the desired result. I searched for the same on net.. bt did not

find any working solution. can anyone pls help me with it?
h

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the `src` attribute in the image tags:

```
$('#div').html($("img[src$='.jpg']").length)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use an [attribute ends with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selector:

```
$('#div').html($('img[src$=".jpg"]').length);
//                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that too. :-) Fixed. I need more coffee.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
var count = 0;

$('body').children('img').each(function() {
  var patt = new RegExp('.jpg$');
  var src = $(this).attr('src');

  if (patt.test(src)) {
    count++;
    alert(count);
  }
});
```

Heres a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/54DPd/1/)